# What is the exact use of fastify-plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I new to fastify framework for node.js, and I'm asking for what is the exact use of [fastify-plugin](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-plugin)
because I can't get the the idea behind it. I tried some code with or without the plugin and I can't notice the difference. except for some behavior like :

1- I can override the decorator I initiate and wrapped it with **fastify-plugin**.

2- I can use and share the decorator with other registered plugins.

Comment: If you don't see any need for this plugin, then why do you use it?

Comment: I didn't say 'There is no need for this plugin', Im just asking for clarification.. because I don't think I understand it :)

Comment: @NicoHaase Also, there are a few places in the documentation that recommend using the plugin without giving clear explanations why / what it does exactly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concept is this one:

- every `register` call will create an encapsulated context
- every `register` + `fastify-plugin` will **not** create an encapsulated context: you will stay in the same context where the `register` was called

An encapsulated context you will use:

- all the hooks in the context and in its parent
- all the decorators in the context and in its parent

Here a visualization:

[image: encapsulation]

so, if you add an `onRequest` hook in the root node (the blue one), **all the routes will execute that hook**.

if you add the `onRequest` hook in the green one instead, ONLY the routes defined in that context will use that hook.

EDIT: I wrote a [blog post](https://backend.cafe/the-complete-guide-to-the-fastify-plugin-system) and a plugin to visualize the structure of a fastify application, so you can generate an image like this example. Checkout [`fastify-overview`](https://github.com/Eomm/fastify-overview)

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: Just to further clarify, If I'm understanding correctly, an `onRequest` hook registered in the purple node would effect the blue node's context and execute for all routes? Would a hook registered in the orange node likewise execute for for all routes since neither it nor the purple node have their own encapsulated context?

More succinctly, is it sufficient to say that a plugin will effect the context of the first plugin within the selection of itself and it's ancestors which was **not** registered with fastify-plugin?