# What's the advantage of fastify-plugin over a normal function call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fastify

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61054534/2505645) does a great job at explaining how `fastify-plugin` works and what it does. After reading the explanation, I still have a question remaining; how is this different from a normal function call instead of using the `.register()` method?

To clarify with an example, how are the two approaches below different from each other:

```
const app = fastify();


// Register a fastify-plugin that decorates app
const myPlugin = fp((app: FastifyInstance) => {
  app.decorate('example', 10);
});
app.register(myPlugin);


// Just decorate the app directly
const decorateApp = (app: FastifyInstance) => {
  app.decorate('example', 10);
};
decorateApp(app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing a `decorateApp` function you are creating your own "API" to load your application.
That said, the first burden you will face soon is **sync or async**:

- decorateApp is a sync function
- decorateAppAsync within an async function

For example, you need to preload something from the database before you can start your application.

```
const decorateApp = (app) => {
  app.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'))
};

const businessLogic = async (app) => {
  const data = await app.mongo.db.collection('data').find({}).toArray()
}

decorateApp(app)
businessLogic(app) // whoops: it is async
```

In this example you need to change a lot of code:

- the `decorateApp` function must be async
- the mongodb registration must be awaited
- the main code that loads the application must be async

Instead, by using the fastify's approach, you need to update **only** the plugin that loads the database:

```
const applicationConfigPlugin = fp(
+  async function (fastify) {
-  function (fastify, opts, next) {
-    app.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'))
-    next()
+    await app.register(require('@fastify/mongodb'))
  }
)
```

> PS: note that fastify-plugin example code misses the `next` callback since it is a sync function.

The next bad pattern will be **high hidden coupling** between functions.
Every application needs a `config`. Usually, the fastify instance is decorated with it.

So, you will have something like:

```
decorateAppWithConfig(app);
decorateAppWithSomethingElse(app);
```

Now, `decorateAppWithSomethingElse` will need to know that it is loaded after `decorateAppWithConfig`.
Instead, by using the `fastify-plugin`, you can write:

```
const applicationConfigPlugin = fp(
  async function (fastify) {
    fastify.decorate('config', 42);
  },
  {
    name: 'my-app-config',
  }
)

const applicationBusinessLogic = fp(
  async function (fastify) {
     // ...
  },
  {
    name: 'my-app-business-logic',
    dependencies: ['my-app-config']
  }
)

// note that the WRONG order of the plugins
app.register(applicationBusinessLogic);
app.register(applicationConfigPlugin);
```

Now, you will get a nice error, instead of a `Cannot read properties of undefined` when the `config` decorator is missing:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The dependency 'my-app-config' of plugin 'my-app-business-logic' is not registered
```

So, basically writing a series of functions that use/decorate the fastify instance is doable but it adds
a new convention to your code that will have to manage the loading of the plugins.
This job is already implemented by fastify and the `fastify-plugin` adds [many validation checks to it](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-plugin#dependencies).

So, by considering the question's example: there is no difference, but using that approach to a bigger application
will lead to a more complex code:

- sync/async loading functions
- poor error messages
- hidden dependencies instead of explicit ones

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question in any form. I understand the difference between `fastify-plugin` and normal fastify plugins, but my question was how is `fastfy-plugin` different from just using a normal TypeScript decorate function over the fastify's `.decorate()` method? Notice the difference in calling: `app.register(fp(plugin))` vs `plugin(app)`

Comment: I will retry: it changes **where** the decorator is attached, so the parent context or the new context

Comment: That still makes no sense, did you read my code example? I'm not talking normal Fastify plugins vs `fp()` decorated plugins, I'm talking `fp()` decorated plugins vs "not a plugin at all but a simple function that I give the app to as an argument".

Comment: Notice how my second code example never uses the `app.register()` method.

Comment: Are you focused on decorator only or all the fastify's features (hooks, error handler, register as well)?
based on that, there is a huge difference regarding how the code is loaded (basically you are writing more code)

Comment: I mean I don't know, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check it

Comment: That perfectly answers my question, sorry for the trouble and thank you for the answer!