# Fastify - Correct way to use Async and best practices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I've been used Node.js/Fastify since October 2022, coming from a PHP background. I understand async/sync to a degree when it comes to fetching data from other API's but I'm struggling to understand it when it comes to routes, plugins and fetching data from a database in Fastify.

After doing some reading, my thought process is why not make everything `async`... Is this bad practice? There seems to be divided thoughts on this from what I've read.

Here's an example below and I have a few questions:

1. The `getInitialTransaction` function in the transactions model
   is `async` but the `const model` variable is not when setting up
   the plugin and it uses `done()`. Is this incorrect and should
   `const model` be `async` instead?
2. If `const model` is changed to `async`, will the register method require `await` so that it looks like this: `await fastify.register(transaction)`.
3. What's the general rule of thumb when setting up a plugin as
   `async` or `sync`? My thought pattern is they should all be `async` so that they're loaded before being used.
4. Is it best to keep DB queries `async` so not to stop the app, especially when queries are quite intensive?

**routes/transactions.js**

```
import formbody from '@fastify/formbody'
import transaction from '../../models/transaction.js'
import * as schema from '../../schemas/transaction.js'

const routes = async (fastify, options) => {

    await fastify.register(formbody)
    fastify.register(transaction) // Is await required if the plugin is setup as async?

    /**
     * Get the initial transaction
     */
    fastify.get('/transactions/initial', schema.getInitialTransactionSchema, async (req, rep) => {
        const transaction = await fastify.transaction.getInitialTransaction(req.query.uuid);
        rep.code(200).send(transaction)
}

export default routes
```

**models/transaction.js**

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'


// Should const model be async?
const model = (fastify, options, done) => {

    const getInitialTransaction = async (uuid) => {

        const connection = await fastify.mysql.getConnection()

        try {
            const [rows] = await connection.query(
                `SELECT t.id, t.amount, t.points, t.currency, t.reference, t.email, m.name AS merchantName, m.points_enabled AS pointsEnabled
                FROM transactions t
                JOIN merchants m 
                ON m.id = t.merchant_id
                WHERE t.uuid = :uuid
                AND t.status = 3`, { uuid: uuid }
            )
            return rows[0]
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            throw e
        } finally {
            connection.release()
        }
    }

    done()
}

export default fp(model)
```

**server.js**

```
import Fastify from 'fastify'
import pino from 'pino'
import autoLoad from '@fastify/autoload'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { dirname, join } from 'path'
import functions from './lib/functions.js'

const fastify = Fastify({
    logger: pino({
        transport: {
            target: 'pino-pretty',
            options: {
                colorize: true,
                ignore: 'pid,req'
            }
        }
    }),
    trustProxy: true,
})

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = dirname(__filename)

const plugins = async () => {

    // Config
    await fastify.register(import('./config/env.js'))
    await fastify.register(autoLoad, {
        dir: join(__dirname, 'config/autoload')
    })

    // Functions
    await fastify.register(functions)

    fastify.setErrorHandler(async (error, request, reply) => {

        fastify.sentry.captureException(error, scope => {
            scope.setExtra('Request', request.body || request.query || request.params)
            scope.setExtra('Headers', request.headers)
        })

        console.log(error)
        reply.status(500).send({ message: error })
    })

    // Routes
    await fastify.register(autoLoad, {
        dir: join(__dirname, 'routes/v1'),
        options: Object.assign({ prefix: '/api/v1' })
    })
}

const start = async () => {
    try {
        await plugins()
        await fastify.listen({ port: fastify.config.PORT || 8080, host: '0.0.0.0' })
    } catch (e) {
        fastify.log.error(e)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

start()
```

Comment: Manuel gives a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515880/whats-the-advantage-of-fastify-plugin-over-a-normal-function-call

If the plugin is not loaded before trying to execute a function contained within the plugin, it will error out. This is my understanding.

Comment: shameless self promotion: all these questions has been discussed in the Fastify book I wrote and which will be released in a month (checkout my profile). I will try to arrange an answer, but the question touches many different topics: how the fastify boots and how the routing and handlers work

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I will definitely be purchasing the book. I've been waiting for it for some time now. I don't feel like there is enough Fastify material online. I've used many different resources over the course of 7-8 months to build projects but I'm still unsure whether I've done certain things correctly. Looking forward to your answers for my questions as I have drawn a blank here. Thank you.