# Decorating Fastify instance returns undefined in route

Tags: fastify

I am trying to add a decorator plugin to my whole Fastify instance so that I can use my mailing service everywhere without having to instanciate a `new MailService` every time I need it. I followed the docs and multiple external plugins integrations like `@fastify/jwt` but when trying to access it from a route it tells me it is `undefined`.

Thank you very much because I am scratching my head since yesterday

```js
// server.ts
import mail from '~/plugins/mail.plugin';
import { user } from '~/router/user/user.route';

app.register(mail, {
  username: 'mail',
  key: import.meta.env.VITE_MAIL_KEY,
  url: import.meta.env.VITE_MAIL_URL,
});

app.register(user);

// ~/plugins/mail.plugin.ts

const mail = (app, opts, next) => {
  const mail = new MailService(app, opts);
  app.decorate('mail', mail);

  // logs properly on the first request
  // `app.mail` is not undefined
  console.log('mail plugin loaded', opts);

  next();
};

export default mail;

// ~/router/user/user.route.ts

export const user = (app, opts, next) => {
  app.route({
    url: '/check',
    method: 'POST',
    schema: CheckUserEmailRouteSchema,
    handler: async (req, rep) => {

      // some code

      // app.mail is undefined
      const token = await app.mail.checkEmail(req.body);
    },
  });

  next();
};
```

### My environment

- *node version*: 18.12.1
- *fastify version*: 4.12.0
- *os*: Windows
- Using Fastify with Vite through `vite-plugin-node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context where your handler executes is different and it is not a child of the context where the `mail` decorator is added.

You need to add to `~/plugins/mail.plugin.ts`:

```
mail[Symbol.for('skip-override')] = true
```

More info:

- https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Plugins/#handle-the-scope
- [What is the exact use of fastify-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020394/what-is-the-exact-use-of-fastify-plugin/61054534#61054534)
- https://backend.cafe/the-complete-guide-to-the-fastify-plugin-system