# Fastify - Access functions within a controller, that are contained within a parent function?

Tags: node.js, fastify

how would you access functions within a controller that are contained within a parent function? In the example below, I am unable to access the `getConfig()` function.

The reason I have it setup in this manner is so that I can still access the Fastify instance in the controller.

**route.js**

```
import formbody from '@fastify/formbody'
import controller from '../../controllers/controller.js'

const routes = (fastify, options, done) => {

   fastify.register(formbody)
   fastify.register(controller)

   fastify.get('/get-config', (req, rep) => {
        getConfig(req, rep)
    })
}

export default routes
```

**controller.js**

```
import merchant from '../models/merchant.js'

const controller = (fastify, options, done) => {

   const srvcMerchant = new merchant(fastify)

   const getConfig = async (req, rep) => {
        const config = await srvcMerchant.getConfig(req.id);

        if (!config) {
            return rep
                .status(404)
                .send({ message: 'Not found' })
        }

        rep.send(config);
    }
}

export default controller
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a plugin (without encapsulation) and add a decorator:

**controller.js**

```js
import merchant from '../models/merchant.js'
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'

const controller = (fastify, options, done) => {

   const srvcMerchant = new merchant(fastify)

   const getConfig = async (req, rep) => {
        const config = await srvcMerchant.getConfig(req.id);

        if (!config) {
            rep.code(404)
            return { message: 'Not found' }
        }

        return config;
    }

    fastify.decorate('foo', getConfig)
    done()
}

export default fp(controller)
```

then in your route:

```js
fastify.get('/get-config', async (req, rep) => {
    return fastify.foo(req, rep)
})
```

Additional useful readings:

- [What is the exact use of fastify-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020394/what-is-the-exact-use-of-fastify-plugin/61054534#61054534)
- https://backend.cafe/the-complete-guide-to-the-fastify-plugin-system

Comment: Thank you for that Manuel. In your opinion, is this the most efficient way to structure a project. I come from a PHP background where I've always used the MVC framework. I feel like I'm always using fastify-plugin whether it's for controllers, helper functions, middleware, services/models, etc.

Can't help but feel I may be over using it and not properly understanding how to leverage Fastify's plugin and encapsulation system.

Thank you for sharing those links by the way.

Comment: This answer requires a book, that I will publish [by august](https://www.packtpub.com/product/accelerating-server-side-development-with-fastify/9781800563582) - I will try to update the answer by collecting some "TLDR" takeaways. eg: if you use the `getConfig` function only in one place, you don't need a decorator

Comment: I am indeed only using ```getConfig``` in one place. I've been following your book for some time now. Has the release date been pushed back? I was under the assumption it was out this month. Very much looking forward to purchasing your book. I feel there isn't enough information online regarding Fastify which makes it a little difficult when building large projects.