# Generating the openapi.yml file after passing the tests

Tags: swagger, fastify, fastify-swagger

After finishing all tests (in tap) I would like to run a script that generates openapi.yml.

In the .taprc config, I added the after property:

```
after: utils/generateOpenApi.ts
```

and my script (utils/generateOpenApi.ts) looks like this:

```
const helper = require('fastify-cli/helper.js')
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const generateOpenApi = async() => {
   const argv = [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'app.ts')]
   const app = await helper.build(argv, {})
  
   console.log('app.swagger', app.swagger)
   const yaml = app.swagger({ yaml: true });
   fs.writeFileSync("swagger.yaml", yaml);
}

generateOpenApi()
```

My main file (app.ts):

```
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from "fastify";
import { buildJsonSchemas, register } from "fastify-zod";
import { join } from "path";
import AutoLoad, { AutoloadPluginOptions } from "@fastify/autoload";
import { type FastifyZod } from "fastify-zod";

import { models } from "./routes/users/users.schemas";

export type AppOptions = {
   // Place your custom options for app below here.
} & Partial<AutoloadPluginOptions>;

// Pass --options via CLI arguments in command to enable these options.
const options: AppOptions = {};

declare module "fastify" {
   interface FastifyInstance {
     readonly zod: FastifyZod<typeof models>;
   }
}

const app: FastifyPluginAsync<AppOptions> = async (
   fastify,
   opts
): Promise<void> => {
   await register(fastify, {
     jsonSchemas: buildJsonSchemas(models, { errorMessages: true }),
     swaggerOptions: {
       swagger: {
         info: {
           title: "Fastify API",
           description:
             "Building a blazing fast REST API with Node.js, MongoDB, Fastify and Swagger",
           version: "0.1.0",
         },
         host: "localhost",
         schemes: ["http"],
         consumes: ["application/json"],
       },
     },
     swaggerUiOptions: {
       routePrefix: "/docs",
       uiConfig: {
         docExpansion: "full",
         deepLinking: false,
       },
       uiHooks: {
         onRequest: function (request, reply, next) {
           next();
         },
         preHandler: function (request, reply, next) {
           next();
         },
       },
       staticCSP: true,
       transformStaticCSP: (header) => header,
       transformSpecification: (swaggerObject, request, reply) => {
         return swaggerObject;
       },
       transformSpecificationClone: true,
     },
   });

   void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
     dir: join(__dirname, "plugins"),
     options: opts,
   });

   void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
     dir: join(__dirname, "routes"),
     options: opts,
     ignorePattern: /.*(schemas)\.ts/
   });
};

export default app;
export { app, option
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/bart-krakowski/contract-tests/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000h3b6rbl93gw7b%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000c3b6rdbk4806g%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000g3b6ruvj9ylz9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000e3b6r829rwnzs%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clkisjpjq000c3b6rdbk4806g%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000b3b6ryl2u9drl%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000c3b6rdbk4806g%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000b3b6ryl2u9drl%2522%257D%252C%2522clkisjpjq000e3b6r829rwnzs%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000d3b6r7g6wqe8k%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000e3b6r829rwnzs%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000d3b6r7g6wqe8k%2522%257D%252C%2522clkisjpjq000g3b6ruvj9ylz9%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000f3b6ra8hbs2r5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clkisjpvk000yhgej1ozeaobq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000g3b6ruvj9ylz9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clkisjpjq000f3b6ra8hbs2r5%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: app.swagger is undefined
# failed utils/generateOpenApi.ts

Comment: Wrap your app.ts with `fastify-plugin` - it should solve. if it works I will explain it more on an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `app.ts` with the `fastify-plugin`.

The structure of your application is like this (on the left):

[image: app structure]

The `helper.build(argv, {})` function returns the `fastify-cli root` instance that does not have the swagger-ui plugin attached.

So, if you break the encapsulation by using the `fastify-plugin`, the `app.ts` lives in the same parent's context and you can access the swagger-ui plugin from the reference returned by `helper.build(argv, {})`.

Further reading:

- https://backend.cafe/the-complete-guide-to-the-fastify-plugin-system
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61054534/3309466
- https://github.com/Eomm/fastify-overview/